# Ember.js: How to track down deferred action runtime errors?

Tags: javascript, debugging, ember.js

I occasionally get the following runtime error.

```
Assertion failed: Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined ember.js?body=1:3226
    (anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:3226
    defaultActionHandlers.error ember.js?body=1:32032
    triggerEvent ember.js?body=1:31884
    trigger ember.js?body=1:30910
    Transition.trigger ember.js?body=1:30131
    handleError ember.js?body=1:31244
    invokeCallback ember.js?body=1:8377
    (anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:8431
    EventTarget.trigger ember.js?body=1:8200
    (anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:8502
    DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js?body=1:5674
    Backburner.end ember.js?body=1:5765
    Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:5804
    executeTimers ember.js?body=1:6056
    (anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:5914
```

The problem is that the entire call stack is ember code. But the error must be caused by my code.

What is a generic approach to determine the original code that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your debugger to stop on all exceptions, then walk up the stack trace and find out what code of yours is firing it.

This particular error looks like you were transitioning to another route and it blew up.  There are only a few things (major understatement) that happen during the transition, I'll point out the biggins that would break the transition, they are all located on the route.

1. overridden `model` hook
2. overridden `setupController` hook
3. overridden `serialize` hook

You'll want to look through your code and add either add some validation that an item exists before you call get on it, or switch to using `Ember.get(obj, property)`, but that just pushes off your exception until later.

I see this error a lot in the `setupController` and `serialize` hook.

```
serialize: function(model){
  // good spot to fail
  return { custom_id: model.get('some_id') };
}

setupController: function(controller, model){
  // good spot to fail
  var something = model.get('something');
}
```

These particular areas speak to a bigger issue, your model hook (or `transitionTo`/`transitionToRoute` code) is passing a null/empty model.